# save query results into multiple SQL tables and do join among these tables (SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to save multiple query results into SQL tables so that I can do join among these query results/SQL tables for further analysis.

First query:

```
with CTE as 
(
   select year, origin, (acX + commX + intX) as totalX,
   RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY origin ORDER BY origin,year)
   from tableX
)
SELECT a.year, a.origin, a.totalX, b.totalX as totalX_lag,
  (a.totalX-b.totalX)/a.totalX as growthX
FROM  CTE as a                      
      JOIN CTE as b     
        ON a.origin = b.origin AND a.RN = b.RN + 1
```

Second query:

```
with CTE2 as 
(
    select year, origin, (acY +commY+ intY) as totalY,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY origin ORDER BY origin,year)
    from tableY
)
SELECT a.year, a.origin, a.totalY, b.totalY as totalY_lag,
    (a.totalY-b.totalY)/a.totalY as growthY
FROM  CTE2 as a                     
    JOIN CTE2 as b      
    ON a.origin = b.origin AND a.RN  = b.RN + 1
```

I need to save the results of the first query as A for example and the second query result as B, and then do the following:

```
select *
from A
join B on A.origin=B.origin and A.year=B.year
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can SELECT * INTO #TemporalTable. For example:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
   SELECT ..
   FROM ..
   WHERE
)
SELECT * INTO #CTE1 
FROM 
    CT1 JOIN WhatEver ON ..
WHERE ...

WITH CTE2 AS
(
   SELECT ..
   FROM ..
   WHERE
)
SELECT * INTO #CTE2 
FROM 
   CTE2 JOIN WhateEver2 
      ON ...
WHERE ...

SELECT ...
FROM 
  #CTE1 JOIN #CTE2 ON ..
WHERE
  ...
```

But probably you don't need temporal tables. You can chain CTE's;

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
   SELECT ..
   FROM ..
   WHERE
)    
, CTE2 AS
(
   SELECT ..
   FROM CTE1 JOIN WhatEver ON .. 
   WHERE ..
)
, CTE3 AS
(
   SELECT ..
   FROM CTE2 JOIN WhateEver ON ..
   WHERE ..
)    
SELECT ...
FROM 
  CTE3 JOIN WhatEver ON ..
WHERE
  ...
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response. But it does not work because what I need to save from query one is more than what's inside the CTE (...), it is the whole section from with CTE as (...), select..., from..., join...on.....I need to save the whole block as a temporary table. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Modified the anwser to address what you say